# UIAlertController crashes with Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

My Alert popup crashes with NSInternalInconsistencyException error. Crashlytics log is below. Following are relevant code snippets. I'm displaying alert in main thread. It's random error so I can't produce it during testing. How to fix this?

**HomeViewController.swift**

```
private func getMessages() {
    fetchMessages() { (result, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            self.showAlert(message: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
}

func fetchMessages(_ completed:  @escaping ((_ result: MessagesRoot?,  _ error: Error?) -> Void)) {

   //...

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error in fetching share content..........")
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed(nil,error)
            }
            return
        }

        do {
            let resultData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MessagesRoot.self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed(resultData,nil)
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            print("JSON Decoding Error")
            print(jsonError)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed(nil,jsonError)
            }
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

**UIViewController+Extension.swift**

```
func showAlertNew(title: String = "", message: String) {

   // ....

    alert = UIAlertController(title: title,message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    // following is line #265
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**Crashlytics Log**

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x19fe8a98c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19f0639f8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x19fda4098 +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
3  Foundation                     0x1a0868088 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x1cc095a44 -[UIAlertController addAction:]
5  myApp                0x10292978c specialized UIViewController.showAlertNew(title:message:) + 265 (UIViewController+Extension.swift:265)
6  myApp                0x1028962a8 closure #1 in HomeViewController.getMessages() (<compiler-generated>)
7  myApp                0x1027afb48 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in fetchListing(sort:asc:_:)
8  myApp                0x1026da0c0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () (<compiler-generated>)
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x19f8c8a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x19f8c97d4 _dispatch_client_callout
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x19f877008 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
12 CoreFoundation                 0x19fe1c32c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
13 CoreFoundation                 0x19fe17264 __CFRunLoopRun
14 CoreFoundation                 0x19fe167c0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
15 GraphicsServices               0x1a201779c GSEventRunModal
16 UIKitCore                      0x1cc915c38 UIApplicationMain
17 myApp                0x1026b50f4 main + 19 (MyProfileViewController.swift:19)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x19f8da8e0 start
```

Comment: Probably because you are presenting from a view/nav controller that isn't the top level item.

Comment: I present alert when user taps on Home Tab which, when tapped, is the top level view.